# Why oracle uses index skip scan for this query?

Tags: oracle, indexing

The SQL queries only one table, the table has 100 millions rows.

The SQL has three columns in the where clause, `col_date`, `col_char1` and `col_char2`. `col_date` is of `date` type, but it has only day part, no time part, like '2016-02-25 00:00:00', this column has about 1000 unique values, and these values spread evenly among the records in the table. `col_char1` is of `varchar2` type, it has about 30 unique values, and these values also spread evenly. `col_char2` is also of `varchar2` type, it has about 20 unique values, and these values spread evenly. where clause is like `col_date >= to_date('2016-02-24 00:00:00') and col_char1 = 'VAL1' and col_char2 = 'VAL2'`. The query result is about 3000 rows.

I created an index `INDEX1` with `col_date`, `col_char1` and `col_char2`, in the order `col_date`, `col_char1` and `col_char2`.

The execution plan is index skip scan using `INDEX1`. I don't know why it uses skip scan instead of range scan. I think skip scan should make this query very slow because the first column (`col_date`) in the index has so many distinct values.

Comment: does the cardinanlty on your query plan match the actual data ? .... are the stats correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The best index for the conditions you have in your question is a composite index on `(col_char1, col_char2, col_date)` (or the first two keys can be reversed).

If you don't have this index, but have a similar index, then I think a skip-scan will be used.

Comment: why the `col_date` column in the index is skipped if it is not at last,  the condition on this column filters out more rows than other two columns. thx

Comment: @roywang . . .Because you have equality conditions on the other two columns and an inequality on the date.